# How can I programatically use Google Voice's "Direct Access Numbers" feature?

Tags: google-voice

How can I programatically use Google Voice's "Direct Access Numbers" feature?

Google Voice apps on Android and iPhone have can directly dial out a number that connects to the target number.

This is different than the two ways that I know of connecting a call:

1) use the (undocumented) API to call you first, then GV connects the target party.
2) call the voicemail#, pause, , pause, <2> ,

Both of those methods provide a less than ideal experience.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a few months old, but I found it when searching on google.  Hopefully this can help some people out.

See this post for details on how to direct dial a number:
http://talk.maemo.org/showpost.php?p=756286&postcount=669

See this thread starting around post 658:
http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=41817&highlight=google+voice&page=67

Also, look at the code for the application qgvdial for maemo / symbian.  It successfully uses this method to directly dial.  Let me know if you have any questions, and I will try to help.

Comment: Awesome. I'll spend some time this week to see if this solves it.